# Getting a Crash Dump for a .NET Application that Uses Native Interop

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

I have a .NET application that makes calls to a native Win32 DLL using interop services.  When I run this program, it will crash somewhere inside the DLL.  However, I have been unable to get any stack dump information.

When I run in the Visual Studio debugger, the debugger exits when the crash happens.  I get the "Blah-blah-app has stopped working. Windows is checking for a solution to the problem...".  If I click the Debug button that appears, I get an error message saying that the process is already open in a debugger, but the debugger from which I launched the app is not functional.

I have tried to enable local crash dumps, following the instructions here: [Collecting User-Mode Dumps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181(VS.85).aspx).  However, no crash dump is generated, and I notice that the page says "Applications that do their own custom crash reporting, including .NET applications, are not supported by this feature."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are using managed debugging which is the default setting for managed projects.  If you're having a crash in a native DLL you'll need to enable mixed mode debugging to get the events and stacks you're looking for.

- Right Click on the project and Select Properties
- Go to the Debug Tab
- Check the "Enable Unmanaged Debugging" checkbox

Repeat your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) from the SDK and use `windbg.exe` to debug the program.

Answer (score 0):

When you get the "*Blah-blah-app has stopped working...*" message, the process still exists. You can find it in the Task Manager, right-click it and select **Create Dump File**.